# Just HOW do I remove this pesky block

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-blocks

I've tried deleting blocks, disabling views - the lot! I just can't get this little block to go away!

A block called "Related Forum" is showing up on our knowledge base pages an example is found - [here](http://www.workbooks.com/help/people_and_organisations).

**I'd like the whole Related Forum block removed from any /help* page**:

[image: pesky block]

If I login and hover my mouse over the block, no settings icon appears.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Navigate to the blocks admin page at "admin/structure/block".
There somewhere you should see your block (generated from a view) named something like "View: related forums".
Click configure and change this blocks visibility settings under the "pages" tab at the bottom of the configure page.

If this does not work, check that this block is not being specifically included in a template file.

Another thing that may be affecting it is the context module.